# C# visual studio 2010 access web elements

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, selenium, web

Is there anyway to access a website elements? For example getting the paragraph text?

I'm able to get contents of elements using Selenium but I don't think Selenium fits this project.

I wanted to access those elements without loading the browser, but in my code below it needs to load the browser and navigate the website.

```
if (this.ean.Text != "")
{
    IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.momox.de");
    IWebElement box = driver.FindElement(By.Id("cInput_home"));
    box.SendKeys(this.ean.Text);
    IWebElement button = driver.FindElement(By.Id("submit_home"));
    button.Submit();
    IWebElement price = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("price"));
    string imageSource = price.GetAttribute("src");
    driver.Close();
    this.price.ImageLocation = imageSource;
} else { 
    MessageBox.Show("Enter EAN"); 
}
```

Comment: Do you want to get the content of an html element in a webpage, if so use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx)

Comment: @MEYWD thanks for the info, so no need for the selenium?

Comment: if you want to do it yourself without the help of external libraries then yes, but it will not be easy to handle since HTML doesn't conform to the XML standard 100%

Comment: that is if you want to parse it using XML manipulation libraries

Comment: What exactly are you intending to do with the elements once you have them? Selenium can use headless browsers too, such as PhantomJS.

Comment: @Arran What I want is to manipulate on the site without "opening the browser and navigate the website". I wanted to get the price of the book using its ISBN in the http://momox.de website. I have to get the id of the textbox and paste the ISBN, then get the id of the button then click it. Then I'll access to the element where the price text belongs.